# If i change android app title in Play Store, will past links then be broken?

Tags: android, google-play

If i change the title of my app in the play store, will past links to the app then be broken? Cause the apps name is a part of the link, so i'm a bit concerned. I mean, I have posted a link to my app to a couple of forums, and if i change the app name, will these links become invalid then??

Thanks very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Cause the apps name is a part of the link

Actually, the application package name is part of the link. Changing the title in Google Play shouldn't affect the link.